# BCE0019: xxx is not a member of 'Object'

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

[image]

I typed `aniPlay=GetComponent("aniSprite")` but seems it did not work, how can I modify it?

Comment: not sure if its same for javascript but in C# you would write `aniPlay = GetComponent<aniSprite>();`. Maybe try that?

Comment: I tried it, in () should I have to add something,cause it has another problem aniPlay=GetComponent<aniSprite>();
}      BCE0043: Unexpected token: ).

Comment: Oh, sorry checked in the Unity manual (you should too :) ) and looks like it should be `aniPlay = GetComponent(aniSprite);` see here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
privat var aniPlay : aniSprite;

function Start () {
    aniPlay = gameObject.GetComponent(aniPlay);
}
```

Comment: but I met another problem   aniPlay = gameObject.GetComponent(aniPlay);
}       BCE0023: No appropriate version of 'UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponent' for the argument list '(aniSprite)' was found.
Maybe there are something wrong in aniSprite? I don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

```
aniPlay = gameObject.GetComponent(aniPlay);
```

This is the correct form of GetComponent, but for this to work you need to make sure the following things:

1. aniPlay is an actual name of a working class
2. Specified gameObject has an instance of that class attached to it

Comment: So I met this problem BCE0023: No appropriate version of 'UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponent' for the argument list '(aniSprite)' was found.     is because Specified gameObject does not have an instance of that class attached to it? I'm sorry I could hardly understand javascript, cause I never learned it before.

Comment: I just noticed that you have the identical names for class and variable (change uppercase/lowercase), I think you might be confusing the compiler with it, try changing it and let me know what happens.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I still don't know why, but I just deleted aniSprite and playerController, retyping them, and then I find it work! Thank you so much! Maybe next time I should try this way.(≧∇≦)ﾉ